# Sending "ENTER" key through serial port

Tags: c#, console, keypress, signals

Hi I want to send some command to my device which is connected via serial port. How to send it?

For example i found this on google search but for me it's useless.

<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is a keyboard shortcut for 5, so:

```
serial.Write(new byte[]{ 5 }, 0, 1);
```

Comment: We need more information about the protocol the device uses to communicate with your computer and vice versa.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The microsoft version of enter or new line is `\r\n` which is `0x0d 0x0a` in hex.

- **`\r` is the carriage return**

  In a shell or a printer this would put the cursor back to the beginning of the line.
- **`\n` is the line feed**

  Puts the cursor one line below, in some shells this also puts the cursor to the beginning of the next line. a printer would simply scroll the paper a bit.

So much for the history lesson. Current windows systems still use these characters to indicate a line ending. Dos generated this code when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

The key code is a bit different. Beginning with the <kbd>esc</kbd> key being the 1. <kbd>Enter</kbd> is 28.

<sup>Source: [linux hlkeycodes from www.comptechdoc.org](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hlkeycodes.html)</sup>

Comment: Thank you i got my answer Matthias.

Answer (score 6):

To send the enter key, you would have to use

```
serial.Write(new byte[]{13,10}, 0, 2);
```

Assuming your syntax for <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>E</kbd> is correct. The enter key is interpreted and usually saved in a file as `CR-LF`.  However, depending on your device, it may only require `CR=13`, or `LF=10`. You should try all 3 combinations with your device to see what it expects.

If you are looking for the actual [scan code](http://www.barcodeman.com/altek/mule/scandoc.php) of the enter key, it's "43" on a PC 102/104 key keyboard. Depending on the actually computer you are using, it may be different. For instance on a [Commodore 64](http://www.c64-wiki.com/index.php/Keyboard_code) the scan code for the <kbd>Return</kbd> key is "1", which has the equivalent use of <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a PC keyboard.

Comment: A little correction, I suspect that the third argument in the Write method could be the number of bytes to be written. If my guess is right, you should change it from 1 to 2.

Comment: Probably right, I'll change that. I don't know the API in this case, but that is a good assumption.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks guys.

This works:

```
serial.Write("\r\n")
```

Note: if you want to send a command through serial port, I use the line below works for me.

```
serial.Write("your_command\r\n");
```

Answer (score 1):

What the previous answers have told you is how to send a NEWLINE character - this is not the same as "the enter key". If what you want to do is to actually indicate to the remote machine that the "enter key" on the keyboard has been pressed, that is entirely different, and may not be possible, depending on your operating system and hardware.

Answer (score 1):

I appended "\r\n" in string and call Write() method and it works for me. For Example,

`serial.Write("abcd\r\n");`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what is ENTER for your device. In Windows it is CRLF (13 and then 10), Linux is LF (only 10.) It's just a matter of what your device expects, because it can't see ENTER, just "byte 10, byte 13, byte whatever..."

Answer (score 0):

You need send the commands CR (Carriage Return) and LF (Line Feed, or new line).

For this is just to send your command plus the the CR and LF like this:

```
string command = "myCommand";

port.write(string.format("{0}\r\n", command));
```

**\r\n = CR + LF -> Used as a new line character in Windows**

Answer (score 0):

To send the enter key, you would have to use
[SerialPort.NewLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) Property - A value that represents the end of a line

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort();
// ... this COM port parameters
_serialPort.NewLine = "\r"; // "\r" - CR (0x0D); "\r\n" - CRLF (0x0D 0x0A)
try
{
    _serialPort.Open();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  Console.Write(ex.Message);
  return;
}
_serialPort.WriteLine("Send string"); // Writes `Send string` string and the `NewLine` value to serial port
 // or
_serialPort.WriteLine((char)2 + "VWD:040" + (char)3); // Writes `<HEX 0x02>VWD:040<HEX 0x03>` string and the `NewLine` value to serial port
```

For a full example of working with serial port, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx).