# Sending ctrl+C over serial port in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port, ctrl

How can I send my device <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> through serial port in C#?

Comment: Why is this tagged C for? C has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Can't you extrapolate the answer easily from the one you got to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805721/sending-enter-key-through-serial-port)? You should be an expert in serial ports [by now](http://stackoverflow.com/users/587674/user587674).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Serial ports don't transmit keys. They transmit bytes, which are normally
the ASCII representations of characters.

"Keys.ControlKey & Keys.C" has to do with sensing what is going on on a PC
keyboard. But serial ports do not transmit the whole state of the keyboard.
For instance, the F keys and the arrows are entirely outside the ASCII
system.

An ASCII chart will tell you that, for instance, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> is 1, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>B</kbd> is 2, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is 3,
'A' is 65, and so on.