# Sending Ctrl+Z to a serial port

Tags: c#, serial-port, at-command

I'm sending AT-Command to gsm modem through serial port.

At the end of the AT-Command I have to terminate the command with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>

How would I do that in serial port?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/4862684/754438

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try this

```
(char)26
```

[detail on ascii of char-z](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-Z)

Answer (score 1):

Send the ASCII character 0x1A.

Have a look at the [ASCII code table](http://www.ascii.cl/)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Command

`port.Write(txt_msgbox.Text + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26));`