# Sending Command from C# Windows form to a microController via serial port

Tags: c#, winforms, serial-port, microcontroller

I am trying to send a command from the windows form application made in C# to a microController thorugh the serial port.

The message string gets passed right, but the problem is the microController never applies the command unless you press Enter, I cannot seem to simulate that Enter press by any means.

I tried appending `"\r\n" , "\n" and Environment.NewLine` to the message string, nothing worked out, What should I do?

Comment: "What should I do?" - post your code...

Comment: What is the code you are using to send commands?

Comment: Pressing enter doesn't magically cause anything to get sent to the serial port.  There's code *somewhere* in your app that is taking that keypress and doing something with it.  Step 1) Find out what that is

Answer (score 0):

Instead of appending the new lines to your message try to send the command separately immediately after you send a message. See this SO [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805721/sending-enter-key-through-serial-port) for some insights. Especially Kibbee's answer:

```
serial.Write(new byte[]{13,10}, 0, 2);
```

A common process when handling strings is to trim them at some point (remove leading & trailing white space.) Sending a new line separately would get around this issue but it could also end up being a hack. First check to make to see if your message string is getting trimmed. Removing the trimming code, if it exists, would be a better solution.