# Sending “ARROW KEY” key through serial port

Tags: c#, console, signals, keypress

In the same way that the question Sending “ENTER” key through serial port 
how can i send the "ARROW key" through the serial port? Most particuly the UP arrow key.

Comment: "The question"? What question are you talking about?

Comment: Any key is defined by a key code and serial communication is just sending bytes. What you need to know is what code the device you're sending to will interpret as an up arrow command. Therefore, the answer depends on the device you're sending to. Also, what René Wolferink said - what question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805721/sending-enter-key-through-serial-port

Comment: when sending keyboard key via serial port i use WriteLine("\n\r") or serial.Write(new byte[]{13,10}, 0, 2) for example to send the ENTER key. What is the equivalent string/byte[] to send up arrow key?

Answer (score 6):

Cursor keys are a relatively new feature of keyboards.  They didn't yet exist at the time the ASCII codes were chosen.  Which was largely based on the capabilities of teletypes that were used at that time.  Like the widely used ASR-33, its keyboard layout looked like this:

[image]

No cursor keys.  Note how line-feed was a separate key back then, '\n' in ASCII.  Easier to get to and affecting the choice for the line-end control character in Unix.  The Return key was the equivalent of the Enter key on a modern keyboard, '\r' in ASCII.

So there are no standard codes to pick for the cursor keys.  You'll have to encode them yourself.  [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) were a common standard.  Emulation of the [DEC VT-52 and VT-100](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) were very common as well.

Comment: +1. Yes, the good old VT100 escape sequences! `Esc[nA` = Move cursor up n lines.

Answer (score 5):

Since ARROW keys are scan codes (not defined in ASCII table), it is necessary to send a sequence of bytes to represent arrow keys (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code for details). Unfortunately, this sequence may vary between different platforms and targets, so you need to experiment for what is correct for your target.
Tested on a Ubuntu 16.04 target from a serial console on Windows, the ARROW UP sequence is three bytes (0x1b, 0x5b, 0x41), or on keyboard: ‘Esc’ ‘[‘ ‘A’

Comment: c# should have predefined structures for keys that should be compatible on multiple platforms without the need to hardcode.