# Why did C choose certain operators to be the symbol they are?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, reference, operators

Exactly as the question says, for education purposes, why did C choose the operators they choose for their corresponding operations. For & of course its simply read "and" so this would make sense. However, I see no connection between & and address or % and modulus or * and pointer. This being said I also don't see a connection between pointer and any real symbol available on the keyboard. Why were these symbols chosen? Were they simply arbitrary? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, [the source of the definitive answer is no longer with us](http://www.wired.com/wiredenterprise/2011/10/dennis-ritchie/). Everybody else's answer would necessarily involve guessing to some degree.

Comment: I believe `*` for pointer comes from the assembler in Digital's PDP series machines. As to why that was choosen by the people at Digital Equipment Corp is of course the next question you'll be asking, and I'm afraid I don't know - I was merely 8 years old when the first PDP-11 was produced in 1972 or so.

Comment: Interesting question. Initially Unix (and C) got some inspiration from the [Multics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multics) OS - and C and PL/1 (Multics was made in PL/1) share a number of similarities. Comparing the C keywords, a system oriented language, to the Cobol keywords, a financial oriented language, is also interesting...

Comment: This is an interesting question, and although the _primary_ source of the definitive answer is no long with us I'm betting he didn't keep it a secret to his grave. There _must_ be other sources. It's a legit question and could have a legit answer.

Comment: A lot of C syntax was inherited from its predecessors: B and BCPL languages, as described by Dennis Ritchie here http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html. For example, the `*` for pointer dereference as well as `*(A + i)` array access semantics came to C from B. Now, why these symbols were chosen in B...

Comment: @Dave: legit by what standard? This is not constructive.

Comment: It eventually comes down to adopting a *convention*: "you just have to agree to something and get on with it" (though in this case, replace *agree* with *pick*). Saying that it is inherited from BCPL solves *this* question, but then why did BCPL use those symbols? Going even further, why does `+` denote addition? Why is the first natural number denoted as `1`? Not pouring cold water over your question though. It is a nice question and a thought provoking one. You have my upvote.

Comment: @先輩 Maybe we don't have to go back to the hieroglyphs... :-)

Comment: @sixlettervariables you won't know if it's a legit question until you get a legit answer. A chicken and egg problem for sure.

Comment: @ring0 :) Well, guess what, if Japanese were the international language, then most likely, you would have to. There too, we agreed to English. (Well, not everyone, but you get the point.)

Comment: @sixlettervariables Not constructive? Some people are interested in the history of the symbolism used. Maybe it's not constructive to _you_. Whether it's documented or not there _is_ an answer, it's not nebulous. Maybe that answer is lost with Ritchie's death (I highly doubt it), but closing the question is nonsense.

Comment: @Dave: [google.com/search?q=why did dennis ritchie use the characters he did for C](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html).

Comment: @sixlettervariables You can find the answer to 99% of the questions here somewhere else on the internet. You think that invalidates the question?!

Comment: Well, again, if you put it this way specifically: "Why did *Dennis Ritchie* use these characters?", then the answer is simple, straightforward and rather useless: because these characters were used in B. The original question really translates to "Why did *Ken Thompson* use these characters?"

Comment: The name of the `&` symbol (ampersand, and) starts with the letter `a`, as does the word "address". Modulus is closely related to division, and the `%` symbol includes a `/`.

Comment: At least with standard C++ you can now use `and`, `or`, and `not`, which are much more readable than punctuation tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) (the standardized first 128 characters) you can see that the choice of characters are quite limited. They simply had no other choice of symbol for those operators.

Except the $, @ and the ` (backtick) characters all printable characters are used.

Probably the first computers C developed on didn't have these three characters in their character set.

Comment: Yes, but you see, why did *they* (K&R) choose symbols over text: in Cobol for instance, the nice and convenient syntax for multiplication is `MULTIPLY Num1 BY Num2 GIVING Result`

Comment: Glad I never had to deal with Cobol... I'd hate to have to try to decipher scientific/mathematical code written in such a verbose manner... "This mere 1.3MB of code right here can balance your checkbook... Unless, of course, it encounters any of the following corner cases:...."

Comment: @ring0 Wow, that's horrible syntax. I love syntax that reads like written english - but math is math. I mean who would even want to do even trivial math writing out the words for *, +, -, /, etc.

Comment: Is this really an answer? Loosely related, maybe.

Comment: The ASR-33 teletype was widely used back then.  Both $ and @ were present.  Keyboard layout is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13686414/17034

Comment: @ring0 - Unlike the big mainframes used to run COBOL, K&R only had [a minicomputer](http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/picture.html). Saving space was important when the compiler had to fit in 12k words.

Comment: @twalberg: I believe that can also be written as `COMPUTE Result = Num1 * Num2`