# Send Enter Key to Serial Port

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have a program that sends and receives data to serial port. I use Tera Term to communicate with the program. I am currently writing a C# program to replace the tera term. I am having issue sending the "Enter" key code to the serial port. The program expects me to "Press Enter Key" to begin. I tried different solutions but none seems to work for me. I tried the following solutions:

```
SerialPort.Write("\r\n");
SerialPort.Write(new byte[]{13,10}, 0, 2);
SerialPort.Write(new byte[]{13}, 0, 1);
SerialPort.Write(new byte[]{10}, 0, 1);
SerialPort.Write(new byte[]{28}, 0, 1);
```

None of the above works for me. Tera Term has a key code application that shows you the key code for the key you press. When I enter "Enter" key, it shows "28". I tried sending "28" to the serial port but that does not work either.

Similar question has been asked in the following post but none of the solutions worked for me. I am developing on Windows 10 operating system.

[Sending "ENTER" key through serial port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805721/sending-enter-key-through-serial-port)

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the correct baud rate, parity bit, data bits, and stop bit. (aka you configured the serial port correctly from the start)? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.-ctor?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: It's probably your flow-control setting.  Nothing you write will actually go out the serial port if the flow control setting is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I had to wait a bit before issuing the "enter" command. The following worked.

```
SerialPort.Write(myCommand);
Thread.Sleep(100);
SerialPort.Write("\r\n");
```